# JavaScript how to create this text background animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

While wandering around the web, I found [this](https://www.midjourney.com/home/?callbackUrl=%2Fapp%2F) animation and wondered how this text background animation can be created.

**Question:**
Im trying to achieve the same animation on my portfolio website, how can I animate this text background animation on my own project?

Comment: Please review [ask] - your question is much too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. If you have an attempt at re-creating this yourself but are running into issues, you can edit your question to include the code you've written thus far as a [mre].

Comment: "*any [...] tutorials on how to make this type of animation?*" Requests for us to find off-site resources for you are explicitly off-topic here per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Review:** I took a look at the website that you have linked and they have multiple text rows that fill out the whole screen, that they continuously manipulate.

**How to achieve an animation:** Select all the text rows with **[JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript?retiredLocale=de)** and precisely modify the DOM using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML?retiredLocale=de). You need to receive random characters and **precisely** modify the DOM in order to achieve a planned out animation.

**Animation:** Set an interval to call your DOM modification function and add some logic to craft a more complex animation.

**Example:** Here is a simple example that I have created, the animation consists of **1 row** and we shift the content to the left and right.

External Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/cjkaqstg/49/

**CSS:**

```
text{
  font-size:16px;
  white-space:pre;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<text id="text-0"></text>
```

**JS:**

```
const text_element = document.getElementById("text-0");
const text_length = 30;
var shift_left = true;

function receiveRandomCharacter()
{
    // Receive a random character
    const characters ="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  return characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length-1) +1];;
}
function modifyText(new_content)
{
    // Function to modify the text content
    text_element.innerHTML = new_content;   
}
function textAnimation()
{ 
  // Add some logic, in this case we will shift the characters to the left and right
  var row_content ="";
    if(shift_left)
  {
    for(var x=0;x<text_length;x++)
    {
        if(x % 2==0)
      {
        // Even Number, add SPACE as a character
        row_content += "  ";
      }
      else
      {
        // Un-even number, add a random character
        row_content += receiveRandomCharacter();
      }
    }
    modifyText(row_content);
    shift_left = false;
  }
  else
  {
    for(var x=0;x<text_length;x++)
      {
        if(x % 2 ==0)
        {
          // Even Number, add a random character
          row_content += receiveRandomCharacter();
        }
        else
        {
          // Un-even number, add SPACE as a character
          row_content += "  ";
        }
      }
      modifyText(row_content);
      shift_left = true;
    }
    console.log(row_content);
}
const interval = setInterval(function() {
    // Call a function every X milliseconds
   textAnimation();
 }, 300);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Do you think I will need to code every step of the animation or it exists an automated way to do it?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes, I will create a simple example.

Comment: You will NOT hard-code every single frame, you will automate it, but you will be required to develop the logic. I hope that my simple example helps you understand how to acquire that.

Comment: Thank you ! that will really help me out, thanks for taking your time on this, really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome! Now you have to create multiple rows and manage them, that way they work together. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you out :)!